# Python: how to implement multiple-inheritance?

Tags: python, oop, subclass, multiple-inheritance

**New to oop. Writing in Python 3.**

I am developing a multiplayer game. 
These are the classes I need:

- a class 'server' - which is the main entry point from which all starts
- a class 'game', that contains the game logic
- a class 'gameroom' to allow multiple simultaneous games to run
- a class 'player' with all the players details
- a class 'session' which is the combination of player and game, containing player related info while playing

[image: diagram of classes]

It seems obvious that session should be a child of both player and gameroom. However, how does an instance of session know which instance of gameroom and player are its parents?

Suppose:

- I have 5 player instances with playerIDs 1,2,3,4 and 5
- I have 2 intances of gameroom with roomIDs 1 and 2.

Now I want an instance of 'session' for playerID = 2 and roomID = 2. How do I 'pass' the roomID and playerID to the new instance of session?

Is this the correct implementation? Or can I somehow implicitly create an instance of session without needing to save player and room in a variable?

```
from player import player
from room import room

class session(player,room):
    def __init__(self, player: player, room: room):
        self.point = 0
        self.player = player
        self.room = room
        print('player {} has joined room {}'.format(player.id,room.id))
```

Comment: TBH it’s not obvious that a session is a specialized player - what about multiplayer games where the session has several players - that phrasing tells me the player(s) are an attribute of a session, i.e. there’s no inheritance. And in general My suggestion is to avoid multiple inheritance and deep inheritance trees as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance is not the right tool here. You should just pass a `player` and a `room` instance to the `__init__` method of `session`.

Inheritance is used to model extensions of classes. If one class inherits another, e.g. `Car` inherits `Vehicle` and you instantiate a `Car` object with `car = Car()`, `car` is also an instance of `Vehicle`.

You can read more on this topic in the application section of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Applications) on inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, assuming that Player and Room have instance attributes name and roomID

```
class Session(Player,Room):
    def __init__(self, name, roomID ):
        Player.__init__(self, name)
        Room.__init__(self, roomID)
        self.point = 0
        print('player {} has joined room {}'.format(name,roomID))
```